# shift particular rows of a particular column of pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have this dataframe[image: df]

And am trying to shift rows which have `NaNs` in the first two columns to the left, so the values to the right now fill this column. Here is what i am currently trying to do:

(Note: the `match` dataframe was downloaded from this link: https://www.kaggle.com/hugomathien/soccer)

```
#original dataframe
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 21374 entries, 145 to 25978
Data columns (total 47 columns):
id                  21374 non-null int64
country_id          21374 non-null int64
league_id           21374 non-null int64
season              21374 non-null object
stage               21374 non-null int64
date                21374 non-null object
match_api_id        21374 non-null int64
home_team_api_id    21374 non-null int64
away_team_api_id    21374 non-null int64
home_team_goal      21374 non-null int64
away_team_goal      21374 non-null int64
goal                13325 non-null object
shoton              13325 non-null object
shotoff             13325 non-null object
foulcommit          13325 non-null object
card                13325 non-null object
cross               13325 non-null object
corner              13325 non-null object
possession          13325 non-null object
BSA                 11856 non-null float64
Home Team           21374 non-null object
Away Team           21374 non-null object
League              21374 non-null object
Country             21374 non-null object
home_player_1       21374 non-null object
home_player_2       21374 non-null object
home_player_3       21374 non-null object
home_player_4       21374 non-null object
home_player_5       21374 non-null object
home_player_6       21374 non-null object
home_player_7       21374 non-null object
home_player_8       21374 non-null object
home_player_9       21374 non-null object
home_player_10      21374 non-null object
home_player_11      21374 non-null object
away_player_1       21374 non-null object
away_player_2       21374 non-null object
away_player_3       21374 non-null object
away_player_4       21374 non-null object
away_player_5       21374 non-null object
away_player_6       21374 non-null object
away_player_7       21374 non-null object
away_player_8       21374 non-null object
away_player_9       21374 non-null object
away_player_10      21374 non-null object
away_player_11      21374 non-null object
winner              21374 non-null object
dtypes: float64(1), int64(9), object(37)
memory usage: 7.8+ MB
```

creating the dataframe

```
columns = match.columns[match.columns.get_loc('home_player_1'):match.columns.get_loc('away_player_1')+1].values
columns = list(columns)

player_appearences = match.groupby(columns[0]).size().reset_index()
player_appearences.rename(columns = {0:"Count_{}".format(player_appearences.columns[0][len(player_appearences.columns[0])-1])}, inplace = True, errors='raise')
player_appearences
for i in range(1,12):
    player_appearences2 = match.groupby(columns[i]).size().reset_index()
    player_appearences2
    player_appearences2.rename(columns = {0:"Count_{}".format(player_appearences2.columns[0][len(player_appearences2.columns[0])-1])}, inplace = True, errors='raise')
    player_appearences = player_appearences.merge(right = player_appearences2,how="outer",left_on ="{}".format(player_appearences.columns[0]),right_on = "{}".format(player_appearences2.columns[0]))
    player_appearences
    #overwrite nans in first column with names in current [i] player column
```

```
#select rows where first two columns give nan values
player_appearences.loc[(player_appearences.loc[:,"home_player_1"].isna()==True) & (player_appearences.loc[:,"Count_1"].isna()==True),["home_player_1","Count_1"]] = player_appearences.loc[(player_appearences.loc[:,"home_player_1"].isna()==True) & (player_appearences.loc[:,"Count_1"].isna()==True),["home_player_2","Count_2"]]
```

When I then print `player_appearences` the dataframe is unchanged. I'm unsure if its either not doing anything, or it is creating a copy of the original dataframe. Can anyone tell me why this isn't working/suggest a better way if there is one?

Comment: Can you include a sample dataframe and not a picture?

Comment: how did u get that dataframe in the first place?

Comment: Based on your description, the easiest may be to split the dataframe into two, dropna on both, then concat them together. Please include a [mcve] including sample input and output and _code for what you're already tried_

Comment: @EdekiOkoh updated the question. Sorry

Comment: you need to share the dataframe as code, so we can paste it into our IDE

Comment: @aws_apprentice i downloaded a pre-made database from here: https://www.kaggle.com/hugomathien/soccer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.rename`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html), then you only need [`DataFrame.stack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) (**`dropna = True`** by default) + [`DataFrame.unstack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html):

```
 df = (df.rename(columns = {'home_player_2':'home_player_1',
                           'Count_2':'Count_1'}).stack().unstack()
       .reindex(columns = df.columns[:2]))
print(df)
  home_player_1 Count_1
0         Aaron       1
1          Adam       2
2         Ziggy       3
3        Zoltan       4
```

Or [`DataFrame.shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html) with [`DataFrame.where`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.where.html):

```
df.where(df.notna(),df.shift(-1,axis = 1)).iloc[:,:2]


  home_player_1  Count_1
0         Aaron      1.0
1          Adam      2.0
2         Ziggy      3.0
3        Zoltan      4.0
```

**Detail**

```
print(df.where(df.notna(),df.shift(-1,axis = 1)))
  home_player_1  Count_1 home_player_2  Count_2
0         Aaron      1.0           NaN      NaN
1          Adam      2.0           NaN      NaN
2         Ziggy      3.0         Ziggy      3.0
3        Zoltan      4.0        Zoltan      4.0
```

Comment: have you used `DataFrame.where`? Have I check column by column? My answer is so different....

Comment: Yeah, right. Your original answer was indeed different, using a different approach (stack/unstack). After I posted an alternative, you have incorporated it to your answer, as if it were there. Shady reputation business.

Comment: I was writing my answer, I didn't copy anything from you, I didn't even see that shift, when I saw all those `isna` I didn't want to keep looking. My answer is clearly different and simple. But the thought is free

Comment: Did you ever think of using where or `iloc` or directly `DataFrame.notna`? Why do you suppose that only you could think of using `shift`? You just published it a minute earlier in an infinitely worse solution

Comment: lol, man, have you already hired a lawyer? you made my day :D

Comment: thanks for the answer. @ansev why is it that you only shift by -1 here? I've tried it and it works but am confused as to why it isn't -2?

Comment: because shift does not take `NaN` values ​​into account

Answer (score 1):

You can use `shift(-1, axis=1)` to shift the columns and `df[df.home_player_1.isna() & df.Count_1.isna()]` to specify which rows to affect. The rows, which you are shifting, should be rewritten in the dataframe.

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['Aaron', 1, None, None],
                   ['Adam', 2, None, None],
                   [None, None, 'Ziggy', 3],
                   [None, None, 'Zoltan', 4]],
                  columns=['home_player_1', 'Count_1', 'home_player_2', 'Count_2'])

home_player_1   Count_1     home_player_2   Count_2
Aaron           1.0         None            NaN
Adam            2.0         None            NaN
None            NaN         Ziggy           3.0
None            NaN         Zoltan          4.0

df[df.home_player_1.isna() & df.Count_1.isna()] = df[df.home_player_1.isna() & df.Count_1.isna()].shift(-1, axis=1)

home_player_1   Count_1     home_player_2   Count_2
Aaron           1.0         None            NaN
Adam            2.0         None            NaN
Ziggy           3.0         NaN             NaN
Zoltan          4.0         NaN             NaN
```

Comment: why `df.home_player_1.isna() & df.Count_1.isna() ` ? maybe better :`df.iloc[:,:2].isna().all(axis = 1)` 
what would happen if they were 50 columns and not 2?

Comment: why not m = `df.home_player_1.isna() & df.Count_1.isna()`? ..
not to calculate it twice..

Comment: Because of the scope of the question. We know that there are 4 columns, and the question is not related to performance.

Comment: I think a solution that can be scaled to more columns is better, that can be easily read and of course more efficient.
If I were OP I would look for the most efficient solution